# Why isn't my Ubuntu displaying on my dual monitors when I'm using usb-c? Is there something I can download or run on terminal?

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

Why isn't my Ubuntu displaying on my dual monitors when I'm using usb-c to dual HDMI? Is there something I can download or run on terminal?
The monitors are being shown however, the display on the monitor is just black. When I move my cursor to the right, it disappears.

All three displays are showing on my Displays in Settings. However, they are all dark.

Everything worked fine on Windows 10. But when I switched to Ubuntu, it doesn't work.

My Computer is HP Zbook-15.

Here's what happens when I list monitors

```
 xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 3
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/309x1080/173+0+0  eDP-1
 1: +DP-1-1 1920/598x1080/336+1920+0  DP-1-1
 2: +DP-1-2 1920/598x1080/336+3840+0  DP-1-2
```

Here's just Zrandr:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.05*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.03  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  71.91    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1-2 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: How are the monitors attached you have not said.

Comment: @David Usb C to dual HDMI! Just updated!

Comment: Are you using the Nvidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: @ChanganAuto No! I have AMD and I did not do anything with it. Do I have to configure it?

Comment: The google results for your model indicated Nvidia graphics, that's why I asked. If you have AMD graphics, either iGPU or dGPU, you shouldn't need to do anything. But you can have an AMD CPU and Nvidia graphics perfectly. Please check your hardware specifications before anything else.